# Axios get request using React useState to store data - data is null

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, axios, state

When I make an API request and then attempt to set the state to the results from the Axios request (after formatting the data a bit) it doesn't work. The request is fine and I'm able to store the data to local variables but the state variable isn't being updated. I removed the StrictMode tags from the parent index.js component so I know that the component is only being rendered once, but I did this because the StrictMode tags were causing another component in my app to display duplicate API data.

Below is the component that I am building, Regression.jsx. I know that I might need to use useMemo but I'm not sure how. Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA

```
import React, { useMemo, useState, useEffect }from 'react'
import ChartBox from './ChartBox'
import {
  Box,
  useMediaQuery,
  Button,
  Typography,
  InputLabel,
  MenuItem,
  FormControl,
  Select
} from '@mui/material'
import FlexBetween from './FlexBetween'
import {
  CartesianGrid,
  Legend,
  Line,
  LineChart,
  ResponsiveContainer,
  Tooltip,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  Bar,
  BarChart,
  ScatterChart,
  Scatter,
  Label,
  ComposedChart
} from 'recharts'
import regression, { DataPoint } from 'regression'
import axios from 'axios'

const Regression = () => {
  const [isPredictions, setIsPredictions] = useState(false)
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [stock, setStock] = useState('AAPL')

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setStock(e.target.value)
    setData([])
  }

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: `https://yfapi.net/v8/finance/chart/${stock}`,
    headers: {
      'x-api-key': '<api key>'
    },
    params: {
      range: '6mo',
      region: 'US',
      interval: '1d',
      ticker: stock
    }
  }

  const stocks = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', 'AMZN', 'NVDA', 'TSLA', 'META', 'XOM', 'WMT', 'JPM', 'KO', 'BAC', 'CSCO', 'MCD', 'PFE', 'NFLX', 'AMD', 'DIS', 'INTC', 'GE']
  const menuItems = stocks.map(stock => <MenuItem key={stock} value={stock}>{stock}</MenuItem>)

  let formatted = []
  let regressionData = []

  const formatData = (x, high, low) => {
    return { x, high, low }
  }

  const regressionDataFormatted = (i, avg) => {
    return [i, avg]
  }

  const regressionCoordinatesFormatted = (x, y) => {
    return { x, y }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let timestamps = []
    let stockData = []

    axios.request(options).then((res) => {
      if (res.data.chart.error != 'null') {
        stockData = res.data.chart.result[0].indicators.quote[0]
        timestamps = res.data.chart.result[0].timestamp

        for (let i=0; i<100; i++) {
          const time = timestamps[i]
          const date = new Date(timestamps[i]*1000)

          const formattedDate = date.getMonth()+'-'+date.getDate()
          const high = stockData.high[i]
          const low = stockData.low[i]
          const avg = Math.floor((high + low)/2)
          const curr = formatData(formattedDate, high, low)
          const currRegression = regressionDataFormatted(i, avg)

          formatted.push(curr)
          regressionData.push(currRegression)
          // setData([...data, curr])
        }

        // setData(formatted)
        // console.log(data)
        const regressionCoefficients = regression.linear(regressionData)

        for (let i=0; i<regressionCoefficients.points.length; i++) {
          const curr = regressionCoordinatesFormatted(regressionCoefficients.points[i][0], regressionCoefficients.points[i][1])
          formatted.push(curr)
          // setData([...data, curr])
        }
        console.log(formatted)
        // setData([...data, formatted])
        // setData(formatted)
      }
      return formatted;
    })
    .then((res) => {
      setData(res)
      console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
    })
  }, [stock])

  

  return (
    <div width='100%'>
      <FlexBetween
                mb='0.25rem'
                p='1rem 1rem'
            >
                <FlexBetween gap='2rem' color='lightgray'>
                    90-Day Summary
                </FlexBetween>

                <FlexBetween gap='2rem'>
                    <FormControl 
                        variant='standard' 
                        sx={{ 
                            m: 1, 
                            minWidth: 120, 
                            justifyContent: 'space-between'
                        }}
                    >
                        <InputLabel id='demo-simple-select-standard-label'>Stock</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                            labelId='demo-simple-select-standard-label'
                            id='demo-simple-select-standard'
                            value={stock}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            label='Stock'
                            sx={{ color: 'white', float: 'right', position: 'relative' }}
                        >
                            {menuItems}
                        </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                </FlexBetween>
            </FlexBetween>

            {/* <ResponsiveContainer width="95%" height={800}>
              <ScatterChart
                margin={{
                  top: 20,
                  right: 20,
                  bottom: 20,
                  left: 20,
                }}
              >
                <XAxis type="category" dataKey="x" name="date" axisLine={false} tick={false}/>
                <YAxis type="number" dataKey="high" name="high" unit=" USD" tickLine={false} axisLine={false}/>
                <Tooltip cursor={{ strokeDasharray: '3 3' }} />
                <Scatter name={stock} data={data} fill="#8884d8" />
              </ScatterChart>
            </ResponsiveContainer> */}

            <ResponsiveContainer width='100%' height='100%'>
              <ComposedChart
                width={500}
                height={400}
                data={data}
                margin={{
                  top: 20,
                  right: 80,
                  bottom: 20,
                  left: 20
                }}
              >
                <Tooltip />
                
                <XAxis dataKey='x' type='number' label={{ value: 'Index', position: 'insideBottomRight', offset: 0 }} />
                <YAxis unit='USD' type='number' label={{ value: 'Price', angle: -90, position: 'insideLeft' }} />
                <Scatter name='high' dataKey='high' fill='white' />
                <Scatter name='low' dataKey='low' fill='purple' />
                <Line dataKey='y' stroke='lightgrey' dot={false} activeDot={false} legendType='none' />
              </ComposedChart>
            </ResponsiveContainer>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Regression
```

Comment: You should revoke that API key that you accidentally included in the original question. It's now on the internet, and somebody will at some point find it and use it.

Comment: Try moving the `let formatted = []` and `regressionData` inside the `useEffect`. The `options` object can also be moved inside.